# How to add video/screenshot to allure html report even if the test passes in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, allure

I am using Allure reporter for my Cypress project. It generates video and screenshot inside the project if a test fails but I want to add video/screenshot even if the test passes. Is there any way to add video/screenshot? Attached is the screenshot of log statements if a test passes

[image]

Comment: FYI you can ask your question directly for the owner [here](https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/issues)

Comment: Not sure but have you tried to use option in `cypress.json` file 
`"videoUploadOnPasses": true,`